# How do you count the characters in a file

Tags: c++, c++11

`while (istr.get()) 
            max++;`

I have this but it is a infinite loop

Comment: If you can use C++17, you might want to consider using [`std::filesystem::file_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size): the link has examples.

Answer (score 2):

You get an infinite loop because `istream::get()` returns an integer that is either a character read from the file, or is an EOF (end-of-file) marker, neither of which evaluates as false (unless a `'\0'` character is read).

You'd probably want this instead:

```
while (istr.get() != std::char_traits<char>::eof())
  max++;
```

Comment: Actually, not `EOF` but `std::char_traits<char>::eof()`.

Answer (score 2):

vu1p3n0x, Jiehong Jiang and Dietmar have pointed out how to fix your current code, but just wanted to point out another option which is more in the spirit of your attempt:

```
char c;
while (istr.get(c)) 
    max++;
```

When you provide a character (by reference) to get, it asks the input stream to store the retrieved character (if any) in that character.  The `get(c)` call then returns a reference to the `istream`, and thankfully testing it in a boolean context does check for the success of the input operation in an intuitive way (i.e. the loop terminates at EOF).

That said - using `filesystem::file_size` - see my comment under the question itself - is far more efficient.

Comment: Of course, `filesystem::file_size` is bound *not* to work. The immediate cases I can think of are: 1. the stream actually isn't a file; 2. the file is opened in text mode on a non-POSIX system using an end of line sequence (e.g. LF/CR); 3. the `std::codecvt` facet used is not the `"C"` facet. It may be preferable to get the correct result rather than a fast one.

Answer (score 0):

here is a return value description from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

> The first signature`get()`returns the character read, or the end-of-file value (EOF) if no characters are available in the stream (note that in this case, the failbit flag is also set).

Another reference of EOF:

> It is a macro definition of type int that expands into a negative integral constant expression (generally, -1).

Since a negative integral is considered as true your while loop will never end.

Comment: The end of file value is guaranteed *not* to be `0` as this is a valud `char` value. The value is `std::char_traits<char>::eof()`.

Answer (score 0):

You get an infinite loop because the `get()` overload you are using only returns a value converting to `false` when the value `'\0'` is read. You want to test for for `std::char_traits<char>::eof()`.

Since the `get()` operation checks whether the stream is in a good state before reading a character the approach is bound to be rather slow. I'd personally definitely prefer using an algorithm:

```
max = std::distance(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(istr),
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Sadly, that's probably still not the most effective way to determine the number of characters in a stream. Without measuring it, I would *guess* that for most implementations this would be the fastest approach:

```
istr.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
max = istr.gcount();
```

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: heh - indeed!

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
int count; //variable to save the count

   do{
      count=istr.tellg();
      istr.get();

   } while( istr.tellg()>0 );
```

or

```
int count;

for(; !(istr.get() & 0) && (istr.tellg()>0); count=istr.tellg());
```